# ImportXML fails - alternative?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a spreadsheet to pull in data from two river gauges near my house to try and follow their relationship to the water level as it passes us, (it's an old mill) since more and more the country seems to be flooding!

Basically the sheet works perfectly but not when the spreadsheet isn't open/when I close the laptop.  I thought `openById` and `getSheetByName` would solve this but I'm having no luck.

The `ImportXML` commands that I construct just return N/A when the sheet is not open.  The script is on a timed trigger every 15mins. I have another basic script that rewrites the contents of the cells as values so that there is only one row of `ImportXML` commands at a time.This script is also on a timed trigger.

I've pasted the scripts below - apologies if they're not very eloquent, these are my first attempts!

```
function fetchData() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AgG7jQSg2ljFdGNpbFRjUTA1LXJwdmtPcmxkQnZpUHc").getSheetByName("River Levels");

var bredURL = "http://www.environment-agency.gov.uk/homeandleisure/floods/riverlevels/120743.aspx?stationId=4004";

var belURL = "http://www.environment-agency.gov.uk/homeandleisure/floods/riverlevels/120743.aspx?stationId=4002";

var ssBredLevel = "substring((//div[@class='plain_text']/p)[2],35,4)";

var ssBelLevel = "substring((//div[@class='plain_text']/p)[2],31,4)";

var ssTime = "substring(//div[@class='plain_text']/p[2],34,5)";

var ssDate = "substring(//div[@class='plain_text']/p[2],43,10)";

var commandBredLevel = "ImportXML(\"" + bredURL + "\",\"" + ssBredLevel + "\")";   // build ImportXML() command

var commandBredTime = "ImportXML(\"" + bredURL + "\",\"" + ssTime + "\")";   // build ImportXML() command

var commandBredDate = "ImportXML(\"" + bredURL + "\",\"" + ssDate + "\")";   // build ImportXML() command

var commandBelLevel = "ImportXML(\"" + belURL + "\",\"" + ssBelLevel + "\")";   // build ImportXML() command

var commandBelTime = "ImportXML(\"" + belURL + "\",\"" + ssTime + "\")";   // build ImportXML() command

var commandBelDate = "ImportXML(\"" + belURL + "\",\"" + ssDate + "\")";   // build ImportXML() command

sheet.appendRow(['Bredwardine',' ',' ',' ',' ','Belmont',' ',' ',' ',' ','=now()']); // append row

var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow(); // define last row

var bredLevel = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 2); // define ImportXML cell

var bredTime = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 3); // define ImportXML cell

var bredDate = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 4); // define ImportXML cell

var belLevel = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 7); // define ImportXML cell

var belTime = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 8); // define ImportXML cell

var belDate = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 9); // define ImportXML cell

bredLevel.setFormula(commandBredLevel);

bredTime.setFormula(commandBredTime);

bredDate.setFormula(commandBredDate);

belLevel.setFormula(commandBelLevel);

belTime.setFormula(commandBelTime);

belDate.setFormula(commandBelDate);

writeFormats();


}

function writeRows() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AgG7jQSg2ljFdGNpbFRjUTA1LXJwdmtPcmxkQnZpUHc").getSheetByName("River Levels");
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.setValues(range.getValues());

};

function writeFormats() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AgG7jQSg2ljFdGNpbFRjUTA1LXJwdmtPcmxkQnZpUHc").getSheetByName("River Levels");

var lastcol = sheet.getLastColumn(); // define width of sheet

var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow(); // define last row

var penrow = lastrow-1; // define penultimate row

var formatting = sheet.getRange(penrow,1,1,lastcol); // fetch formatting from penultimate row

formatting.copyFormatToRange(sheet,1,lastcol,lastrow,lastrow); // paste formatting to last row

};
```